# Joomla Article Multilingual Associations

Tags: php, joomla-3.3.x, multilingual

I am confused. I have a Joomla 3 multilingual website. I managed to associate menu items and everything else, but I have a page where there is an article and below the article I put Joomla Article Category module to display other articles titles from the same category in Dynamic mode.

Besides menu associations, I also associated my categories and all articles in three languages so that in another page where a category blog is set after clicking on an article you can then change the language and be redirected to the corresponding translated page without a menu linking to the article.

The problem is that when I click in the module Article Category, it opens my article, but then when I click to the language flag to change the language to English for example, it redirects me to the English homepage.

Why does it happen so? How can I solve this problem without creating menu items for all articles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a very similar site than your, but only in 2 languages, and this association is working for me, just make sure, that you have done these steps:
- Associate categories (you have already mentioned)
- associated articles  (you have already mentioned)
- set the language at each article (funny but I failed to do so)
- set up menus for the category blogs (if you do not want to show them on the main menu then in a hidden menu)
- set the language for each menu item
- associate the menu items as well. 
- set the language at the module that displays the articles

If everything is set and still do not work, that is probably a bug in joomla.

Comment: Thanks, I have already found that solution, you are right. The mistake was that I mentioned the menu item as a single article, not a category blog.